# c++ get users cursor position in console "cells"

Tags: c++

System: Windows; Version c++23
Want to create an interactive button in a console application.
For this to work, I need to get where a user clicked 1) relative to console window 2) NOT IN PIXELS, but in CONSOLE CELL UNITS.
Things I tried:

```
using namespace std;
void GetMouseCursorPos(POINT *mC) {
    *mC = POINT{0,0};
    ScreenToClient(GetConsoleWindow(),mC);
    mC->x = mC->x / font.dwFontSize.X;
    mC->y = mC->y / font.dwFontSize.Y;
    system("cls");
    cout << mC->x << " " << mC->y;
}

int main (){
    POINT mCoord;
    while (true){
        SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | 
 ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
        GetMouseCursorPos(&mCoord);
    }
}
```

In fullscreen ALWAYS outputs 0 -4
Second try:

```
using namespace std;
void GetMouseCursorPos(POINT *mC) {
    *mC = POINT{0,0};
    ScreenToClient(GetConsoleWindow(),mC);
    mC->x = mC->x / font.dwFontSize.X;
    mC->y = LONG(mC->y - 22.5) / font.dwFontSize.Y;
    system("cls");
    cout << mC->x << " " << mC->y;
}

int main (){
    POINT mCoord;
    while (true){
        SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | 
 ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
        GetMouseCursorPos(&mCoord);
    }
}
```

Although 2nd try is better (but still not perfect)
[Why the 2nd try is not perfect(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A088.png)
When you click on the red crosses
you select the slot leftside to it (not the slot itself)

Button class:

```
using namespace std;

class Button {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int height;
    int width;
    string text;
    string text1;
    string text2;
    int color = 7;
    int itemColor = 7;

    string getText() { return text; };

    void setText(string text) { this->text = text; };

    bool isPressed(int mX, int mY) {
        if (mX >= this->x && mX <= this->x + width && mY >= this->y && mY <= this->y + height) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    void print() {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {static_cast<SHORT>(x + 1), static_cast<SHORT>(y)});
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), color);
        for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++) {
            cout << "-";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (height - 2); i++) {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                                 {static_cast<SHORT>(x), static_cast<SHORT>(y + i + 1)});
            cout << "|";
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                                 {static_cast<SHORT>(x + width), static_cast<SHORT>(y + i + 1)});
            cout << "|";
        }
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                             {static_cast<SHORT>(x + 1), static_cast<SHORT>(y + height - 
1)});
        for (int i = 0; i < width - 1; i++) {
            cout << "-";
        }
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                                 {static_cast<SHORT>(x + 1),
                                  static_cast<SHORT>(y + height / 2)});
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
        for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << text;
        for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        if (!text1.empty()) {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                                     {static_cast<SHORT>(x + 1),
                                      static_cast<SHORT>(y + height / 2 + 1)});
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text1.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), itemColor);
            cout << text1[0];
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
            cout << text1.substr(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text1.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        if (!text2.empty()) {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                                      {static_cast<SHORT>(x + 1),
                                      static_cast<SHORT>(y + height / 2 - 1)});
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 7);
            for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text2.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << text2;
            for (int i = 0; i < width / 2 - text2.length() / 2 - 1; i++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling the function [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) with the argument `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT`, you can set the console to report mouse events. These events can then be read using the function [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).

When reading a mouse event, you will get a [`MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str) structure. The `dwMousePosition` member of this structure is in character-cell coordinates, not pixels.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD ir;
    DWORD dwRead;

    //set console to report mouse input events (but nothing else, including keyboard events)
    if ( !SetConsoleMode( hInput, ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT )  )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error setting console mode!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while ( ReadConsoleInput( hInput, &ir, 1, &dwRead ) && dwRead == 1 )
    {
        //ignore all non-mouse events, except for the key "q", which is a request to end the program
        if ( ir.EventType != MOUSE_EVENT )
        {
            if (
                ir.EventType == KEY_EVENT &&
                ir.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown &&
                ir.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar == 'q'
            )
            {
                return 0;
            }
                
            continue;
        }

        //ignore all mouse events which don't involve mouse button presses
        if ( ir.Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags != 0 && ir.Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags != DOUBLE_CLICK )
            continue;

        //determine whether mouse button was clicked or released
        if ( ir.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState != 0 )
            printf( "Mouse button clicked" );
        else
            printf( "Mouse button released" );

        //print coordinates of mouse click/release
        printf(
            " at the following cell coordinates: [%u,%u]\n",
            ir.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X,
            ir.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y
        );
        fflush( stdout );
    }

    fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Mouse button clicked at the following cell coordinates: [24,9]
Mouse button released at the following cell coordinates: [24,9]
Mouse button clicked at the following cell coordinates: [46,10]
Mouse button released at the following cell coordinates: [60,12]
Mouse button clicked at the following cell coordinates: [45,17]
Mouse button released at the following cell coordinates: [31,10]
```

In order to quit the program, you must press the <kbd>Q</kbd> key.

Note that this program is only for demonstration purposes and is not optimized for performance. In a proper program in which performance may be an issue, it would probably be better to read more than one event at once using `ReadConsoleInput`.

Comment: Can you please link an example? Would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Lavarite there's an example linked in the linked documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events

Comment: @Lavarite: I have now added an example program. Sorry that it took longer than expected.